# My Arduino waveform generator using for loops won't cycle

Tags: for-loop, arduino, comparator, wave

I'm a new programmer and I've got a couple of questions about this program I'm writing for an Arduino.

Here is what I am trying to do:

- Create an 8-bit triangle wave generator using a pair of for loops that trigger each other.
- Control the time between increment/decrement of the wave to manage frequency.
- Compare an 8-bit variable, `threshold1`, to the amplitude of the wave and flip an led on match.

I am running into 2 problems:

1. My increment/decrement condition in both for loops is not triggering unless I comment out the second half of the logic as I have below.
2. The leading edge for loop and the falling edge for loop trigger once and stop without re-triggering. I am failing to understand why that is.

I have tried reaching out to a couple of friends with more experience than me, but they are both stumped. I started using the serial monitor to debug, which got me as far as getting one successful cycle out of the waveform generator, and working flip flop (if I comment out the second half of the logic condition as I have below).

What I am hoping to learn is how can I change my code so that the for loops re-trigger as intended after a full cycle, and what is the best way to address increment/decrement with multiple conditions (2 or more comparisons)?

Here is my code:

```
/* this program is my first attemp to design a dual window comparator within the arduino for use in a eurorack environment.
/ the basic premise is a 8bit triangle waveform generator and two 8bit variables. when the wave and variable match a
/ flip occurs, so 4 flips per period, on off on off, and when those occur (and therefore, the duty cycle of the pwn square
/ output) is controlled by the 2 threshold variables */

// constants won't change. Used here to set a pin number:
const int ledPin = 13;// the number of the LED pin

// Variables will change:
int ledState = LOW;// ledState used to set the LED
long stpLngth = 200; //triangle wave step length TODO make an analog read do this and make a scaler to make it exponential control ei v/Oct

void setup() {
  // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  // Time comparison for setting the wave frequency:
  unsigned long currentMillis = 0;
  unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

  byte threshold1 = 0b01100000; //starting position 98/256
  byte threshold2 = 0b10000000; //starting position 128/256
  // I will add code to handle a second threshold once I get the for loop to work as expected
}

void loop() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
  unsigned char wavePosition = 0;
  byte threshold1 = 0b01100000; //starting position 98/256
  byte threshold2 = 0b10000000; //starting position 128/256  
  long stepLength = 200;
  //this variable is to compare to the difference between currentMillis and previousMillis, and control frequency. TODO write a tap tempo and a mapped analog control for this
  /*This is the leading edge of my triangle wave, I want it to initiate a waveat 0 and increment if:
   * a) it's less than 254 and 
   * b) (currentMillis - previousMillis) is equal or greater than stepLength*/

  //I've commented out the extra logic conditions I was trying to use to control the frequency below and now it increments, but I am still hoping to learn a way to control the time between steps:
  for(wavePosition=0x00; wavePosition<0xff  /*&& ((currentMillis - previousMillis) >= stepLength)*/; wavePosition++) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    Serial.println("increment waveform");
    //this is for debugging it prints each time the wave decrements
    if (threshold1 == wavePosition) {
      //compares threshold1 to wavePosition flipflop led on match
      if (ledState == LOW) {
        // if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
        ledState = HIGH;
      } else {
        ledState = LOW;
      }
      Serial.println("Led flip 2");
      //this is for debugging it prints when the led changes state
      digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
    }
  }

  // falling edge of wave same logic conditions commented out, this one decrements but at the end of the waveform it doesn't restart the rising edge for loop it just hangs.
  for(wavePosition=0xff; wavePosition>0x01/* && ((currentMillis - previousMillis >= stepLength)*/; wavePosition--) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    Serial.println("decrement waveform");
    //this is for debugging it prints each time the wave decrements
    if (threshold1 == wavePosition) {
      //compares threshold1 to wavePosition flipflop led on match
      if (ledState == LOW) {
        // if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
        ledState = HIGH;
      } else {
        ledState = LOW;
      }
      Serial.println("Led flip 2");
      //this is for debugging it prints when the led changes state
      digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Serial.begin(9600);` should always be in the `setup()` function. Even running a simple "Hello World" program with `Serial.begin(9600);` in the `loop()` function may fail.

Comment: That solved the issue, now it loops. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The code contains a lot of bugs (which makes sense, since you said you are a beginner - hang in there). The biggest things I'd suggest are:

1. As a beginner, declare all of your variables before `setup()` and `loop()` and don't re-declare them later.
2. Move all of your initialization code into `setup()`.
3. Make sure `loop()` doesn't contain any setup code.

Remember that when your Arduino sketch runs, the Arduino will call `setup()` just once, then it will call `loop()` over and over forever.

For example, as Nitred pointed out, `Serial.begin(9600)` should be inside `setup()` and not inside `loop()`. Also, I see `threshold1` and `threshold2` are set and declared both in `setup()` and `loop()`. Instead they should be declared before `setup()` and `loop()` and set in `setup()`.

Fixing those things won't make the code run correctly, because the code contains several other bugs, but it will make it easier for you to find the other bugs. For example, the loops aren't behaving the way you want with regard to `currentMillis` and `previousMillis` because the start of `loop()` resets those variables each time `loop()` is called.

Good luck and keep at it.
Brad

Comment: Excellent advice!